# How to stream data to BigQuery using Flink Stream and SQL API

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Is there any Flink connector available (sink) for BigQuery streaming? From BigQuery docs, there are two possible ways to stream the data,

1. [Legacy BigQuery streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)
2. [Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api)

From BigQuery documentation, it looks like the storage write API is preferred one. I tried to find sink connector for both the above types but I am not able to find anything in the Flink docs. Any possible way to achieve this? Document says it is possible to write custom sink, but I am not sure where to start and how. Any documentation/blogs available to write own sink (using DataStreamAPI and SQLAPI)?

Comment: I see that there is an open JIRA ([FLINK-22665](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22665)), so there is no official support, probably you need to write your own sink. [This](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sourcessinks/) might help as a start.

Comment: Did you find any breakthrough on this thread? @invisible